# Why should the error_log file be private

Tags: php

I have been seeing alot of posts explaining how to make the error.log file private . But can anyone tell me why is it dangerous to be public or what are the risks?

Answer (score 5):

The error log file will expose paths and software versions. These will make it a lot easier to know what to target and where things are located.

You might also be inadvertently logging sensistive data which you don't want accessed.

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted. This is exactly how the likes of wordpress vulnerability scanners get some of their information. It might not be the sole reason for keeping logs private, but its a large consideration